# Dediacting something to friends on facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph, sharing, tagging

I have a music website. And, I want that users listening the sounds have ability to dedicate that sound to any of their friends on facebook. Firstly, I thinks to go with Open Graph's Tagging ability, so that user able to dedicate the sound. But, Tagging requires that the friend tagged in the story should actually be with the person taking the action. But in my case it is not possible, because Dedcating a Sound needs only one user who is dedicate the music to user. And mention tags also not supposed to be used, because the Action is independent to the mention tags. But in my case, the Dedicate action is wholly dependent on the Tags. Then, Explicit sharing comes to vision, but according to documentation in Facebook Developers portal, it is inappropriate to label the actions as explicitly shared, which are low level type like following, friending and passing. 
I just need a direction that how to enable Dedicating A Sound feature with facebook's open graph. If Dedication is not a low level action like following, friending and passing & is possible with Explicit Sharing, please let me know. Otherwise, please tell the way how to i construct the action Dedicate a sound to Friends.
Thank U in advance.